# Somehow display XKCD title text in the OneBox

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, tooltips, onebox

SE Chat already knows how to render xkcd links: you get the comic image, hyperlinked to the URL, with the title text behind the image:

```
<div class="onebox ob-xkcd">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="https://xkcd.com/1607">
        <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/supreme_court.png" title="Writing for the majority, Justice Kennedy called the man's arguments that he could be either Alito or Ginsburg &quot;surprisingly compelling, but ultimately unconvincing.&quot;" alt="Writing for the majority, Justice Kennedy called the man's arguments that he could be either Alito or Ginsburg &quot;surprisingly compelling, but ultimately unconvincing.&quot;">
    </a>
</div>
```

On mobile devices, though, it's practically impossible to get the title text for an image. On xkcd in particular, the title text is usually a key part of the joke, leaving mobile users missing out on half the fun.

Can we get Obie to print the title text, perhaps as a caption beneath the image?

Comment: Obie being [our](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) name for the One Box.